# Object killing itself issues

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have been trying to come up with an idea to force object to kill itself while it is allocated on stack. Steps are as follow:

1. Allocate object dynamically
2. Pass a reference or pointer of vector holding this object
3. Push object to a vector
4. Delete object from step 1
5. Call method `destroySelf` on object in vector

Code example:

```
class Foo
{
   std::vector<Foo> *ownVector;
public:
   Foo(std::vector<Foo> *ownVector) : ownVector(ownVector)
   {
      std::cout<<"Foo ctor"<<std::endl;
   }
   bool operator==(A const &b){ return true; }
   bool removeItself()
    {
        std::vector<Foo>::iterator iter = std::find(ownVector->begin(), ownVector->end(), *this);
        if(iter != ownVector->end())
        {
            ownVector->erase(iter);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    ~Foo()
    {
       std::cout<<"Foo dtor"<<std::endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Vector created:" <<std::endl;
    std::vector<Foo> fooVector;
    std::cout << "Foo obj created on heap:" <<std::endl;
    Foo *foo = new Foo(&fooVector);
    std::cout << "Foo object pushed to vector:" <<std::endl;
    fooVector.push_back(*foo);
    std::cout << "Foo object dealocated from heap:" <<std::endl;
    delete foo;
    std::cout << "Call removeItself:" <<std::endl;
    fooVector.at(0).removeItself();
    std::cout<<"Main end";
    return 0;
}
```

Results are as follow:

```
Hello world!  
Vector created: 
Foo obj created on heap:  
Foo -ctor  
Foo object pushed to vector:  
Foo object dealocated from heap:  
Foo -dtor  
Call removeItself:  
Foo -dtor 
Main end
```

First question: what is the risk of such implementation?

Second question: when I tried to implement copy constructor

```
Foo(Foo const &foo){ std::cout<<"Foo cpyctor"<<std::endl; }
```

it started to crash on removeItself call. Why is that?

To answer the questions: I am aware that vector owns copy of given object. The whole point of this idea was to destroy objects alocated on **stack** on demand. The big picture was that object is created and pushed to vector and it is the only running instance in the program. Then when certain condidtions are met object will alone decides when to destroy itself.

I tried to do this out of curiosity, because it seemed to work (printing messeges) i tried to go step ahead and then copy constructor crashed program.

Comment: I don't think this code does what you think it does ... ownvector is holding copies of your objects; and every time you call removeItself, you try to remove the first item in the vector...

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You have a **copy** of `*foo` in `fooVector[0]`, it is entirely unrelated to `*foo`, especially after you have deleted it.

Comment: Also: `ownVector` is a very confusing name for a member pointer that does not indicate ownership. Your copy constructor doesn't copy the members of `Foo`

Comment: Do you perhaps want a `std::vector<Foo *> ownVector;`?

Comment: I THINK what you want is std::shared_ptr and std::weak_ptrs... but it's hard to tell given that we've no idea what your big picture is.

Answer (score 3):

> to force object to kill itself while it is allocated on stack

By this I assume you mean to explicitly destroy (and deallocate space for) an object with *automatic storage duration* before its normal lifetime end. This **cannot be done**. You can explicitly control only the lifetime of objects of *dynamic storage duration* (i.e. objects created by `new`). All other objects (of automatic, static and thread storage duration) have the lifetime managed by other rules (scope end, program end and thread end respectively). These rules cannot be circumvented in any way.

So in short if you need to manually destroy an object you need to make that object of dynamic storage duration.

Or, depending on your use case you could create a scope to control the point of destruction. E.g.:

```
void foo()
{
   // ... code   

   { // scope block

       Foo f;

       // ... code

   } // f destroyed

   // ... code
}
```

But you need to be careful to not hurt the readability of the code by doing so.

If this is an academic exercise (e.g. pure curiosity) then the above is the solution. However if you encountered this while trying so solve some problem then your question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: "This cannot be done", just for curiosity sake, is this really true in general ? I'm not sure, but invoking the destructor of an automatic variable and then calling std::abort() (or something equivalent) should be legal by itself ... or not ?

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes hmm... I just scanned the standard and §12.4.15 seem to suggest your scenario is OK.

Comment: Another way to destroy an object that supports move semantics in c++11 is to move it to a smaller scope temporary. The two objects are effectively swapped, leaving your original uninitialised, whatever that means for the object, then the small scope of the child will destroy the original data. For example 'myvector = MyVector();' is a common way to ensure vector releases all memory usage, rather than keeping a big empty array hanging around. I'm sure you can do something with decltype, and perhaps with std::move to avoid having to name the type explicitly.

Comment: @GemTaylor moving from objects by no means destroys them. The standard non-trivial types are left in a **valid** but unspecified state and custom types will have a custom behavior.